# How to locate lines we drew on the chart e.g. for marking trends, support/resistance? Pine Script V5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

There you can see two horizontal (dotted white) lines on the chart below, placed manually.
Is it possible to make the script retrieve their locations?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, accessing to user drawn objects is not possible.

Comment: It could be quite a rock'n'roll function. Don't you know how to submit feature requests?

Comment: Well, it might not be as handy as you think it would. Both sides involved (user and coder) need to know exactly what they are doing. The backlog is full of awesome features anyways, so stay tuned :)